# Are .eml attachments a security risk?

Tags: email, security, microsoft-outlook, attachments

My email service provider blocks mails with attached `.eml` files, apparently for security reasons, with the result that I loose relevant mails.

I have tried to find a description of the current security risk of forwarding mails with `.eml` files attached, but I could only find posts about 10 years old about vulnerability in Outlook.

What are the current risk of mails with `.eml` attachments, and is blocking by an email service provided still relevant ?

Comment: I would contact that service provider and say them that it's not their business to block any email.

Comment: I tried that, but they said that filtering in general helps a lot for their other users, and that the filtering is server wide, so now I try to figure out if this filter is actually required, or I can go back to them and say that they can remove it...

Comment: They should be able to remove attachment filtering on your account only, if they say they cannot try another email provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What are the current risk of mails with .eml attachments ?

Risks described [in this post](http://help.ready-set-go.biz/email/eml_attachments/) are still the [risks with mails with .eml attachments](https://support.tvcnet.net/help/kb/article/80-Email-Attachments-and-Viruses) because of old *IFrame exploits*, *MIME exploits* and viruses like Nimda

> In some email clients, such as Microsoft Outlook, .eml files can
>   trigger active scripting that can be used to launch virus activity. 
>   Furthermore, other executable file types can be wrapped in .eml files
>   in order to bypass other virus checking scans.  Therefore, many ISPs
>   and email servers block the .eml file type.

### Is blocking by email service provider still relevant ?

This is debatable topic.

But if service provider wants to take the ownership of filtering emails for you, they must provide you with a quarantine zone where you can check what emails are blocked and if you want them to be delivered or not

Answer (score 2):

The [Nimda virus is known to create EML files](http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/EML-Microsoft-Outlook-Express-mail-message-MIME-RFC-822).  When EML files are found as an included attachment it is good practice to scan with anti virus before opening.